# My application accounts disappear after reboot

Tags: android, android-account, android-external-storage

I'm saving accounts for my application, saving works well and accounts are saved and accessible trough accounts and sync menu in settings.

On some devices after reboot the account disappears. I detected it on old devices Samsung Galaxy Tab running with Android 2.2, I don't know if it will happen on other devices.

If the application is moved from external memory to device memory the bug disappears. I saw on some forums that accounts are not loaded in this case because the external memory is not mounted while the OS loads the accounts.

Is there a way to fix this problem other than forcing the app to be installed in device memory in manifest?